# c# 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Tags: c#, string, list

I do not understand, what is the problem?

my code:

```
public List<string> files = new List<string>();
string bb="C:\\cpqsystem";
files.AddRange(bb);
```

error description:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>)' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
```

Comment: Ok! I understand about range, why does this code work fine? it is just string too.

if (openFiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    files.AddRange(openFiles.FileNames);
                    //MessageBox.Show(openFiles.FileNames);
                }

Comment: FileNames is not a simple string, it is a string[] so it is an IEnumerable<string>. FileName property is a single string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bb` is just one string, not a collection of them (it's a collection of chars), so you just want to use `Add` (i.e. `files.Add(bb)`).

Answer (score 2):

As specified before you should use `Add` for a single string.

If you actually want to use `AddRange` you should create an `IEnumerable<string>` with your string (for example an array):

```
files.AddRange(new[]{bb});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AddRange()` function expects an `IEnumerable<T>` collection as its argument ( hence the error `cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` ) and adds the collection to the end of the specified `List<T>`. Since you are trying to add a single string, you should use the `Add()` function :

```
files.Add(bb);
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddRange` adds a collection of entries to a list, so it's expecting an IEnumerable. You're  only supplying a single string, so you should use the `Add` method.

Try

```
files.Add(bb);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a String in a List of Strings with addrange you need to have an `IEnumerable<string>`.

To add a single string to a List of Strings, you have to write in this way:

```
public List<string> files = new List<string>();
string bb="C:\\cpqsystem";
files.Add(bb);
```